# how to convert varchar to numeric or double in sql query

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

Database connector error: ADO Error code: 0x80004005

> Error converting datatype varchar to numeric

i tried with this:

```
SELECT CAST(debit as DECIMAL(9,2)) FROM sum_balance
```

Comment: Show what is present in `debit` column

Comment: Can you please add some more detail. It seems like you are converting money, does that mean there are dollar signs in the old varchar column? Does the column also contain commas? would those symbols extend the after decimal characters past 9 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),'You Value here'),2)
```

This will convert your varchar to decimal and will show 2 digits after decimal

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right, but the error you are getting is probably because there is some data in your table that cant be converted to numeric value, a possible unexpected character in one of the values .

A way around would be something like

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(debit) = 1 
            THEN CAST(debit as DECIMAL(9,2)) 
         ELSE NULL 
       END  AS debit
FROM sum_balance
```

AS NoDisplayName has pointed it out ISNUMERIC function will return true for a value like 123e11 , because it sees as a 123^11 or 123 raise to the power of 11 . A way around would be to use the following:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN debit NOT LIKE '%[^.0-9]%'
            THEN CAST(debit as DECIMAL(9,2)) 
         ELSE NULL 
       END  AS debit
FROM sum_balance
```

Comment: What if data is like `'1e3'` or `'$1232345'`

Comment: FYI `ISNUMERIC` returns **true** if the value can be converted to a numeric data type. This includes `real, float, money`. For that reason non-number characters like `'+', '-', 'd', 'e', '$','£'` are allowed

Comment: I have updated my answer @NoDisplayName I knew when I was answering this question, someone is going to come up with this question. its sorted anyway :)

Comment: Second query looks good :)

Comment: SELECT CASE WHEN debit NOT LIKE '%[^.0-9]%'
            THEN CAST(debit as DECIMAL(9,2)) 
         ELSE NULL 
       END  AS debit
FROM sum_balance

this code works fine but i can't add another column which is also in varchar type if i try to add this with code it shows the same error converting data type, i need credit and debit column with decimal or integer type and a sum of these two and accumalated balance too. is there anyway to do this